# Batch File - opening files in specific order

Tags: batch-file

The problem that I'm having is in a batch file where at the end I try to open two explorer windows and then a notepad .txt file with instructions on copying a file from one folder to the other.

When I execute the batch file, the .txt file will open in between the two explorer windows, when I would like for it to open on top. Is there a way to make that happen? Thank you for your time!

```
    explorer "C:\program files (x86)\SEL\SEL5010"
    explorer C:\users\public\temp\SEL5010

    ECHO. >>C:\users\public\temp\SEL5010\Instructions.txt
    ECHO Hello %username%, >>C:\users\public\temp\SEL5010\Instructions.txt
    ECHO. >>C:\users\public\temp\SEL5010\Instructions.txt
    ECHO Copy SEL5010.lic >>C:\users\public\temp\SEL5010\Instructions.txt
    ECHO. >>C:\users\public\temp\SEL5010\Instructions.txt
    ECHO FROM: The C:\users\public\temp\5010 folder.
    ECHO   TO: The C:\Program Files (x86)\SEL\SEL5010 folder. 

    notepad C:\users\public\temp\SEL5010\Instructions.txt
```

Comment: Try replacing `notepad` with `explorer` also. To make this work correctly you need to go into something deeper then batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you say "on top" do you mean "maximized"? in that case, try

```
 explorer "C:\program files (x86)\SEL\SEL5010"
 explorer "C:\users\public\temp\SEL5010"

 echo Some instructions >%temp%\instructions.txt
 START /MAX notepad %temp%\instructions.txt
```

for more information on other parameters you may use, read `HELP START`

However, if you just want to display some instructions, why not put them directly in the console?

```
ECHO Some instructions
PAUSE
```

or in a message box?

```
(echo msgbox "Some instructions" >%temp%\m.vbs) && call %temp%\m.vbs
```

to elaborate further this second method, you can put a message box with the contents of a text file

```
(echo msgbox  CreateObject^(^"Scripting.FileSystemObject^"^).OpenTextFile^(^"%temp%^\instructions.txt^"^).ReadAll >%temp%\m.vbs) && call %temp%\m.vbs
```

Comment: That was a helpful solution, thank you! The msgbox ended up working the best for me, it looks a lot less clunky that just opening a text file up.

Comment: I can't yet =/ need more reputation, then I will.

Answer (score 0):

this works here:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
explorer folder1
explorer folder2
PING -n 2 localhost >nul
notepad file
```